# A Banach space is $\sigma$-compact iff finite dimensional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, compactness

Reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644183/infinite-dimensional-sigma-compact-space) I learned that a Banach space is $\sigma$-compact iff finite dimensional. The $\impliedby$ direction is obvious, but I cannot find a proof of the $\implies$ direction, I checked Conway, Brezis and DiBenedetto, but they barely mention $\sigma$-compactness.

How do you prove this fact or where can I find a proof of it?

Comment: I believe (check this) that it is possible to find an uncountable set $S$ with no limit point in any infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$. If $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, then it is the union of countably many compact sets. At least one of these must contain uncountably many elements of $S$. By compactness, $S$ has a limit point, a contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** First show that in infinite dimension compact sets have no interior points (recall that the unit ball is not compact). Now assume that $X$ is $\sigma$-compact and pick a family $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of compact sets such that
$$ \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n = X.$$
Now $X$ has an interior point. Use Baire's Theorem to show that this leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact infinite-dimensional Banach space, with $X=\cup_n K_n$. By the Baire category theorem, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $K_n$ has nonempty interior.  But compact sets in infinite-dimensional normed  spaces always have empty interior.

To prove the claim made in this last sentence, assume $X$ is an infinite-dimensional normed space, and $K\subset X$ is compact and has nonempty interior $K^\circ$. Since scaling and translation are homeomorphisms in normed spaces, we may assume without loss of generality that $K$ contains the open ball of radius $>1$ centered at $0\in X$.  Then applying induction and the [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), we obtain a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ with no convergent subsequence, contradicting the fact that $K$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

From Chapter 25 of Willard's *General Topology*, we have the following nice theorem:

> A $\sigma$-compact space $X$ is Baire iff the set of points at which $X$ is locally compact is dense in $X$.

You can combine this with the fact that a topological vector space is locally compact iff it is finite-dimensional to prove that any $\sigma$-compact Baire topological vector space (including any $\sigma$-compact Banach space) must be finite-dimensional (since a topological vector space is locally compact iff it is locally compact at one point).