# Is any $\sigma$-compact space a union of two countable unions of pairwise disjoint compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-compact topological space, meaning that $X = \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} K_i$ for a sequence of compact subsets $(K_i)$.

Does this already imply that $X$ can be written as a union

$$\tag{1} X \,=\, A\cup B \qquad\text{with} \qquad A \,=\, \bigcup_j K^{a}_j \quad\text{and}\quad B \,=\, \bigcup_k K^{b}_k$$

where each $(K_\nu^{\gamma})_\nu$ [$\gamma\in\{a, b\}$] is a sequence of pairwise disjoint compact sets?

Comment: @Jose But $(K_j)$ isn't necessarily a sequence of pairwise-disjoint sets....   The required sequences can certainly be found if the space is locally compact, but I don't know otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of distinct uncountable sets, $x$ a point not in any $X_i$, and $X = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty X_i \cup \{x\}$. Say that $Y \subseteq X$ is open if it either doesn't contain $x$, or it contains $x$ and $X_i \setminus Y$ is finite for all $i$ - essentially take countably many copies of uncountable space with discrete topology, take Alexandroff extension of each, and glue them by the extension point.

Each $X_i \cup \{x\}$ is compact: any open cover of it includes some neighbourhood of $x$, which also includes all but finitely many points from $X_i$, thus we can choose finite subcover. So, $X$ is $\sigma$-compact.

But all compact subsets of $X$ include points from only finitely many $X_i$: if $Y$ includes points from infinitely many $X_i$, then let $Z \subset Y$ such that $Z$ is infinite and intersects infinitely many $X_i$ in $1$ point, then $\{z_1\}, \{z_2\}, \ldots, X \setminus Z$ is open cover of $Y$ that has no finite subcover. Moreover, any compact subset that doesn't include $x$ is finite.

So, if we represent $X$ as union of compact sets, some of them are finite, and the rest include $x$ together with points from finitely many $X_i$. If our union is countable, then, as every $X_i$ is uncountable, every $X_i$ has points from some compact set containing $x$. But as every compact set containing $x$ intersects only finitely many $X_i$, and there are infinitely many of them, there is infinite amount of compact sets containing $x$ in the union.

Thus any representation of $X$ as countable union of compact sets includes infinitely many distinct sets that include $x$, and thus can't be split into finitely many sequences of sets where all sets from one sequence are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Thanks! Would you know if the asserted decomposition $(1)$ (of $X$ into two the countable disjoint unions $A, B$) does hold if $X$ is in fact a separable Banach space?

Comment: $\sigma$-compact Banach spaces are finitely dimensional (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3055040/659499), so it trivially holds (if you require $\sigma$-compactness; otherwise it trivially fails).

Comment: Thank you. If you're okay with one final question, would you know if the desired decomposition $(1)$ holds if $X$ is an arbitrary [ie, *not necessarily linear* ] $\sigma$-complete closed subset of a separable Banach space?

Comment: Sorry, what is $\sigma$-complete?

Comment: Apologies, I meant $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Well, my example is not even separable itself, so I think there should be intermediate question "is any $\sigma$-compact separable space union of two sequences of disjoint compacts" (and also we can ask "is it union of countable many compacts such that: (a) any point belongs to at most $n$ compacts; (b) any point belongs to only finite number of compacts"). The answers are non-obvious to me (and neither was to your original question), so I think they deserve separate questions. Out of curiosity - what is the motivation behind this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I agree that it would be good to ask a separate question; I will do that soon. The motivation behind the question is that I want to construct a special function on $X$ as a series of weighted indicator functions over compact subsets, and it would be desirable if said subsets delivered a partition of $X$; since a partition this is too much to hope for, I instead aim at the sum of two functions which 'disjointly decompose' the indicators $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$, respectively. The ultimate goal of this whole construction is an approximation problem.